# How to use wildcards in Batch programming?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to move certain groups of files using wildcards to a folder that is created by the group's filename. The names of the files are stored in "events.txt".My batch file is running uptil the last line. It is displayed that my syntax is not correct.

```
echo off
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (events.txt) do call :makemove %%A
pause 
exit

:makemove
set f=%1
set file=%f:~0,-4%  
md X%file%
set dest=C:\Users\sony\Desktop\X%file%
move /y "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\*%file%*.*" "%dest%"
```

Comment: There is a space after file variable assignment expression - is it just a post typo? If it also exists in your script, that would cause an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there are whitespace characters after

```
set file=%f:~0,-4%
```

line.

This causes the last line of your script evaluate to

```
move /y "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\*foobar  *.*" "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\Xfoobar  "
```

and messes paths up.

Comment: Please mind the backslash after %dest% variable in move command. Without it, %dest% would be interpreted as a file name, not directory name.

Comment: Thanks Helbreder for the answer! But it still didn't solve my problem. First of all, the move command is working for multiple files, when i`m using it in another folder. I mean this code is working but I have to enter the filenames individually (which i am trying to avoid) `echo off
set /p file=Write the name of the file:
md X%file%
set dest=C:\Users\sony\Desktop\Intern @ ONGC\DATA\X%file%
move /y "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\Intern @ ONGC\DATA\*%file%*.*" "%dest%"
pause
exit`.

Comment: But when I'm using my script, it is displaying, "The filename, directory name or the volume label syntax is incorrect". I think it has something to do with the computer confusing between filename and directory name, but I am using the backslash as u mentioned. It would be very helpful if you could look into that. (PS: i tried your other script but it didn't work too. Actually i have just started using batch 2 days ago, so I dont fully understand it n feel comfortable with my own script)

Comment: Hmmm... I wonder what may cause symptoms you describe. Please double check that there are no spaces after line `set file=%f:~0,-4%`.

Comment: Thanks man! that worked. You are a life saver! I had a tab space after that line. But I still dont understand what effect the space had on the script...

Comment: Batches are literal to the bone. If `file` variable is defined with spaces, it treats it that way. Let's say `file` variable is assigned with "foobar  " (without quotes). `md X%file%` works, because spaces are at the end of expression and they are ignored by the md command. `move /y "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\*%file%*.*" "%dest%"` evaluates to `move /y "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\*foobar  *.*" "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\Xfoobar  "` and it messes up paths to actual files.

Comment: Seems like my previous answer was inacurate - move command does operate on wildcards. I should modify my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Like Helbreder pointed out, there is a space after `set file=%f:~0,-4%`.
To avoid this type of problems you can use the extended syntax of `SET`.

`set "file=%f:~0,-4%"`

The surrounding quotes will ensure that only all characters until the last quote are part of the string.
The quotes itself are not part of the string.

So even this would work

```
set "file=%f:~0,-4%"    the spaces and this text will be removed
```

Another positive effect from the quotes is that they will avoid problems with special characters in the filename, like in `Cat&Dog`.

So your code should look like

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (events.txt) do call :makemove %%A
pause 
exit

:makemove
set "f=%~1"
set "file=%f:~0,-4%"
md "X%file%"
set "dest=C:\Users\sony\Desktop\X%file%"
move /y "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\*%file%*.*" "%dest%"
```